# Quartz X11 under Yosemite does not respect Alt key

Tags: macos, terminal, x11, osx-yosemite, xquartz

I don't use it often, but now (after Yosemite came) I opened the XQuartz terminal and tried to enter `ssh -X user@machine`. But it did no longer accept the alt-key being pressed. None of the alt-chars shows up. It's always the original letter appearing. For the time being I ended up using a shell command with the at-sign inside and calling that, but that can't be the final solution. Note: I have already checked all combinations of the Input settings in the preferences for the keyboard. I also rebooted (feel like a Windoze user meanwhile).

Answer (score 0):

After long time revisiting this question I felt the need to verify it. And voila

```
XQuartz 2.7.11 (xorg-server 1.18.4)
```

(and maybe an earlier version) has addressed the issue and the alt-key is working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, at the end I updated XQuartz, but maybe only with checking the option that says "Option keys send Alt_L and Alt_R" and restarting should work